# Can a Supervised Routine be Compared Against an Unsupervised?

Tags: machine-learning, unsupervised-learning, supervised-learning

Just a question out of curiosity. Suppose that I had generated:

(1) an unsupervised decision tree using 'interpretable clustering,' and (2) a second supervised decision tree (whether CART, or a decision tree from the optimal decision tree paradigm).

If I had these two decision trees available to me, is it somehow possible to evaluate what the inclusion of a dependent variable brings to the party, rather than just using visual inspection of both trees?

Would be helpful if anyone knew of anything here, such as an objective score/information criteria/whatever. Or similarly, if people just thought this was a ludicrous question. All feedback welcomed.